# To repeat the same action as a routine

Tags: phrase-request

Ís it correct to say,"to live just because" instead of  "to live just by doing" in order to give to understand that somebody does something just by routine, without any willpower?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the idiom "in a rut" deserves your closer attention as it seems to respond to your request very well.

The noun [*rut*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rut) literally means a track worn by a wheel or by habitual passage, and figuratively — a usual or fixed practice; a monotonous routine.

So figuratively, ["in a rut"](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rut) means "in a type of boring habitual behavior" ("as when the wheels of a buggy travel in the ruts worn into the ground by other buggies making it easiest to go exactly the way all the other buggies have gone before" [cited from the same source]).

Typically it is used in the expressions:

***Be (also be sucked )in a rut*** meaning to do the same things all the time so that you become bored, or to be in a situation where it is impossible to make progress

> My job bores me—I feel I'm in a rut.
>
> David felt like he was stuck in a rut, so he went back to school.

***Get in(to) a rut*** meaning to become seemingly trapped or stuck in a mundane, non-changing pattern of life, work, and/or personal behave:

> I got into a rut, cooking the same things week after week.
>
> We're getting in a rut — let's move abroad for the summer and shake
>   things up!

and

***get out of a rut*** meaning the opposite:

> Moving to San Francisco gave her the chance to get out of a rut.

Answer (score 0):

The normal idioms for that are:

To be in a [rut](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rut) (noun definition 2)

> a usual or fixed practice; especially a monotonous routine "fall easily into a conversational rut"

To do things by [rote](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rote) (or by rote habit) (definiton 2)

> mechanical or unthinking routine or repetition "a joyless sense of order, rote, and commercial hustle" — L. L. King

You might also see, a little more metaphorical, "To be running on autopilot"

"To live just because" isn't an idiom, and to me indicates a more happy or care-free sense than I think you're trying to convey.